# WP won't save changes in post (any)

Tags: pages

My WordPress does not save any changes in any post.  I can create a new page or post and that one will be saved as 'Draft' but there is no content inside. When I make changes, press UPDATE it shows no error or something and the update button becomes inactive as it should. Then in a seconds a message appears saying 'The backup of this post in your browser is differ...'

I still able create new and edit plugin entities like ninja forms, sliders etc. without any problems. The issue affects builtin WP posts only.

### Tried:

- Folders/files permissions: checked and ok.
- disable all plugins: did not help
- browser cache cleared: did not help
- switch to another browser: did not help
- latest version installed.

What else should I check?

For now, I can only change post content directly in DB field.

Comment: Have you tried opening your browser console to see if there are any JS errors? Also, are you using the Block Editor or Classic, or a page builder?

Comment: @WebElaine, no significant errors as far as I can see. I see awarning about non-unique elements thou, but not like it could be the matter. I'm using Gutenberg If there is a correct answer. But If I disable all plugins it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

That was file/folder **owner** issue.