# Wordpress won't save any post

Tags: posts

my issue is similar to the one addressed in this question ([WP won't save changes in post (any)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/354994/wp-wont-save-changes-in-post-any=)

Long story short: all of a sudden 3 wordpress install stopped working. I type a post, hit "save as draft" - or publish - and everything seems fine at first look, but actually the post is not saved.
If I go back to the dashboard > All posts, the post has been saved with title "Quick draft" and is completely emtpy. Also permalink is not saved.
Oddly enough I can save a draft post using the dashboard home feature - the small box that lets you add content quickly from the dashboard home page. I can also upload images but I cannot set a featured image - the loader keeps spinning but the image is not attached to the post.

I suspected a cache issue, so I cleared the cache from my Hosting panel, but had no luck.
I tried the Health Check diagnostic, but the plug-in diagonstic was fine.
I disabled all the plug-ins, reverted to TwentyTwenty theme, cleared cache again, but still no way to save a post.

I contacted the hosting provider had a chat with a customer care rep who flushed the cache and I manage to save one post, but after that I had the same problem again. Wordpress is up-to-date (version 5.5.1) and the dev versions of two of the websites work on my local install - so I don't think it's a plug-in conflict.
As a workaround I managed to write the post on the local version, export it and then importing on the live website and it works, except that the post doesn't have a featured image (it doesn't get imported).

---

EDIT
I tried to add a new post using the Classic Editor plug-in that I deactivated long ago. And now I can save posts as long as I keep on using it. So Gutenberg seems the problem.
This is just a workaround, unfortunately.

---

The hosting provider says it's a development issue and I should ask a developer, since everything's ok on their side.

Any suggestion before changing the hosting provider?

Comment: It does sound like a development issue to me, but try deactivating all plugins, switch to the Twenty Twenty theme (which I presumed was never modified?), and reinstall WordPress via the Dashboard → Updates page. Then see if those steps help.

Comment: Hi Sally, thanks for the suggestion. I tried deactivating everything and switch to TwentyTwenty and nothing happened. I haven't tried re-installing Wordpress from the dashboard, though but it looks like a good idea. I'll try later today as soon as I have finished doing a backup. I also tried to re-activate the Classic Editor - I haven't used it since Gutenberg launched and now at least I can save the posts - I'll edit the original question.

Comment: Hello @SallyCJ, I tried to reinstall Wordpress via the Dashboard but the problem persists.

Comment: This certainly wont be a hosting issue. If it's only affecting Gutenberg then it might well a JS issue. My bet is that it's plugin related. I'd try deactivating those one by one (with Gutenberg back on) and keep checking.

Comment: @kikaweb "So Gutenberg seems the problem." - try disabling the Classic Editor plugin and then check the browser console for any errors upon saving a post. You can also try [debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).

Comment: @SallyCJ I tried to deactivate everything and switch to TwentyTwenty, but the problem persists. The first thing I did was switching on the debug in my wp-config but it's not giving me any clue, no errors at all. If I switch off the Classic Editor I have no error in my console. But if I reactivate the Health Check plug-in - the only plug-in active - I get one REST API warning "The REST API did not process the context query parameter correctly." but honestly I don't know much about REST API. That happens on all 3 websites.

Comment: @vancoder as per my reply to Sally, I tried to follow your suggestion but there's no error in the console, not even a warning. Just the REST API warning in the Health Check plug-in.

Comment: @kikaweb Maybe there's a plugin or code is messing with the REST API response - do you have any Must Use plugins (in `wp-content/mu-plugins`)? (note that those plugins cannot be deactivated via the Plugins admin page) Try visiting `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post` (replace the domain name with yours) and see if the response is good (a valid JSON string/data).

Comment: @SallyCJ the mu-plugin folder contains only the Health Check plugin Troubleshooting file - and that was installed later for the troubleshooting. If I visit the URL I get a JSON string with the details of the only post type of my site (taxonomy, slug, etc.). wp/v2/posts outputs correctly all the posts.

Comment: There are 3 possible causes of the issue: 1) There's an error in whatever JS file/code (but you didn't notice the error), 2) The REST API endpoint (I don't know which one) isn't returning a valid response, or 3) Maybe it's actually a caching issue that has not been fully resolved. And if you can let us access one of the sites (as an editor?), then we might be able to help you identify the problem - and give a more precise suggestion on solving the problem. If that's not possible, then you should consider hiring someone to further check the issue.

Comment: @SallyCJ no problem for an editor access, is there a way to DM the credentials? By the way, I really appreciate that you're willing to spend some time helping me with this. Regarding the cache: I have no active cache plug-ins and I disabled Siteground "Super Cacher" Cpanel module to exclude any caching.

Comment: @kikaweb I deleted my previous comment, but thanks for the editor access. And apparently, from what I could tell, it seems that the server isn't sending (and neither reading) the `X-WP-Nonce` header and other headers such as `X-WP-Total`. So please upload [this file](https://gist.github.com/5ally/c732703bbc38539d1429893fea1ee2ae) to the root directory (where you can see the `wp-config.php` file) and let me know here once done.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. I uploaded the file and it gives a 500 - Internal Server error.

Comment: Change the `echo` line to `echo isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_WP_NONCE'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_WP_NONCE'] : 'NA';`

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get a 500 error.

Comment: Then I guess it's the `header()` part that's causing the error? Try removing it, but if it's still giving the error, then that's really odd, unless you made a mistake in the file data like unwanted characters.

Comment: Yep, it was the header. Now I get "NA" as output.

Comment: The problem is solved, but since I don't know how it happened I won't post an answer. After removing some malicious files hidden in my WP installs, and after the support downgraded the PHP version to 7.1, everything works. Honestly, I don't know what did the trick, but I wish I knew. Thanks to @SallyCJ for supporting me through the troubleshooting.

Comment: @kikaweb, despite you don't know how it happened, you should still add that comment as an answer (or add it to the question) because it was a solution that worked - i.e. you ran a security scan and PHP was downgraded by the hosting support (although that one doesn't sound right...). And btw, it's good to see the REST API on your site is now serving the correct headers like `X-WP-Nonce` - you can check it on httpstatus.io (use `<your domain>/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` or any other REST API URLs on your site).

Comment: I posted the solution as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Following advices from other contributors I'm posting here the "solution" for future reference, just in case someone is experiencing the same issues.

As I wrote in one of the comments, while investigating the REST API problem - by the way, I'd have never narrowed it down without some help from @SallyCJ - I found out some malicious files in all three Wordpress installs. I wasn't looking for malware or exploits, I simply stumbled upon some suspicious php files that weren't supposed to be on my server. Hosting support helped me doing a thorough security scan, so I could remove all the nasty files.

I don't know why but when the malicious files where detected the support staff automatically downgraded my PHP version from 7.3 to 7.1.

Honestly, I don't know what did the trick - the cleaning or php downgrade - and even the support staff had no clue, but right now all the websites are working, I can post new content using the block editor and everything seem to work just fine.