# Wordpress doesn't save or publish new posts

Tags: posts, publish

This problem started when I wanted to create a new post. I'm using the Elementor editor, so I created a new post, set the title and featured image and then clicked on "Edit with Elementor" as usual. While Elementor was loading, I got [this error](https://elementor.com/help/the-content-area-was-not-found-error/?utm_source=editor-panel&utm_medium=wp-dash&utm_campaign=learn).

My first thought was that this is an Elementor issue. But then I tried to first create a new post and then save it as a draft or publish it first before editing it with Elementor, and to my surprise, nothing happened. No matter what I do, I always end up with an "auto-draft" with no content which I can't change for the life of me. Can't change the name, slug, or to be precise, I can't save any changes.

The funny thing is that this happens only for posts but not for pages. I can create new pages and edit old pages and posts without problems.

Tried deactivating plugins I installed since publishing my last post, clearing the cache, using a different browser, updating everything, but nothing worked. I'm not currently using a caching plugin and I see no errors in devtools.

Any idea what could be wrong?
I saw [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/375633/wordpress-wont-save-any-post) where they were doing something with the REST API, but I have no idea what that is, so I can't tell if I can help myself with it.

Comment: You can try the troubleshooting steps I suggested (e.g. deactivate plugins and switch to a default theme) in my comments on the linked question and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I tried deactivating all plugins and switching to the twenty-twenty-one theme, but the issue persists.
I've been thinking, the last thing I was doing was dequeuing some css files manually and replacing them with my own to optimize the website, but I tried reversing that and it didn't help either.

Comment: Then maybe you should hire someone to check the issue for you.. but some other things you can try, in no specific order: 1) Clear your site and browser caches. 2) Reinstall WordPress (core files). 3) Run a security scan on your site. 4) Check the `.htaccess` file for anything suspicious.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. I tried clearing caches and I checked htaccess file, all seems fine. When running a few different security scans, the only error I get is "could not find the wp-content directory". However the wp-content directory is where it has always been. Could this be a permissions thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to my problem.

In my case I had set a 301 redirect for my front page (that is for "domain.com") to another page I wanted to use as the front page. Apparently that caused a problem when Elementor tried accessing it's content (although I'm not sure why it needs the content of my front page if I'm creating a new post).

So I removed the 301 redirect and just changed which page is set as the front page in Wordpress.

**To clearify**: I was avoiding the front page setting because I was afraid what was going to happen to all my backlinks pointing to the page I was redirecting to. But when you change your front page in Wordpress, the page's URL becomes "domain.com" and it's previous url "domain.com/page" is automatically 301 redirected to "domain.com". Which means that all links are kept unharmed.

---

**Edit**: I finally got rid of the problem. As it turns out, my redirect was only a part of the problem concerning only Elementor. But the ability to save/publish posts in Wordpress turned out to be an internal Wordpress error. After a few weeks of dealing with this issue I finally got an error when clicking on 'Publish' inside Wordpress, saying: "The response is not a valid JSON response".

After browsing around a while I found out that I was far from being alone in this issue. It turns out it is connected to permalinks, I found that [this article](https://wordpress786.com/updating-failed-error-message-the-response-is-not-a-valid-json-response/?unapproved=313&moderation-hash=fb09f323203bbb265314ac01339cbfae#comment-313) explains it best.

I was able to fix the issue by either changing the permalink structure to 'plain' or by installing the Classic Editor plugin. Since plain permalinks are not acceptable for me, I chose the second. I'm sure this could also be resolved in a more elegant way, but I'm not proficient enough with backend development to do it. Hopefully this will be resolved with future Wordpress updates.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution, but how did you set the 301 redirect? Perhaps adding the details would be helpful to others who might be having the same or a similar problem.

Comment: Actually, I spoke to soon. Removing the 301 redirect did help me to access a new post with the Elementor editor, which I san use normally now. But if I want to publish any changes in Wordpress directly (like set a featured image), no changes are saved.
My redirect looked like this: `RewriteRule ^/?$ https://domain.com/page/ [R=301,L]`